# Re-order columns in a text file by a specific pattern

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I'm very new at awk and have been banging my head trying to get this to work.   I'm trying to take a list of files in "image.list" and create an "info" file out of it.  I need to grab the string matching a regex (a number 8-11 digits long) from the middle of the filename and print just that match into the designated spot in my "info file".  That last part is the part I'm having trouble pulling off.  Would love some help fixing that.

Here is my test file list:

```
SURGERY0001275678image1.jpg
SURGERY11134900211image2.jpg
SURGERY19257012image3.jpg
SURGERY273142590image4.jpg
```

Here is my current code:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "-----TEST TAG FILE\tENCOUNTERS-----";}
> {print "FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/"$1,"\t","ENCOUNTER: ",($1~/^[0-9]{8,11}$/);}
> END{print "END REPORT";
> }' image.list > upload.tag
```

And here is my current output:

```
-----TEST TAG FILE      ENCOUNTERS-----
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY0001275678image1.jpg        ENCOUNTER:  0
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY11134900211image2.jpg       ENCOUNTER:  0
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY19257012image3.jpg          ENCOUNTER:  0
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY273142590image4.jpg         ENCOUNTER:  0
END REPORT
```

What i need it to display is the 8-11 digit number in the middle of the file name after "ENCOUNTER:".  So far everything I've tried outputs either the whole filename or "0".

I'm probably way off course so I'd love to get some help from you experts!

Comment: The return value of the `~` operator is whether the match succeeded (1) or failed (0). You're getting 0 because none of the filenames match your regular expression.

Comment: Is the part before the number always the same length?

Comment: ahh, that makes sense, no wonder!  The file name lengths can vary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-using your existing code:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    print "-----TEST TAG FILE\tENCOUNTERS-----";
}
match($0,/[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+/,ary) {
    print "FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/"$1,"\t","ENCOUNTER:"ary[1]
}
END { 
    print "END REPORT";
}' testfile
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat testfile
SURGERY0001275678image1.jpg
SURGERY11134900211image2.jpg
SURGERY19257012image3.jpg
SURGERY273142590image4.jpg

$ awk '
> BEGIN {
>     print "-----TEST TAG FILE\tENCOUNTERS-----";
> }
> match($0,/[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+/,ary) {
>     print "FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/"$1,"\t","ENCOUNTER:"ary[1]
> }
> END { 
>     print "END REPORT";
> }' testfile
-----TEST TAG FILE      ENCOUNTERS-----
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY0001275678image1.jpg        ENCOUNTER:0001275678
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY11134900211image2.jpg       ENCOUNTER:11134900211
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY19257012image3.jpg          ENCOUNTER:19257012
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY273142590image4.jpg         ENCOUNTER:273142590
END REPORT
```

*As Ed Morton suggested in the comments, using array argument to match() this solution is GNU awk only.*

Comment: Wow, that works great!  Thanks a million!  To try and understand what exactly is going on here... it looks like you're doing a match into an array, or is that a variable called "ary" ?

Comment: Yes, we are using `awk's match` function to capture the match in to an array and then using it later.

Comment: Here is a good [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions)

Comment: You should state that that solution is GNU awk specific courtesy of the array argument to match().

Comment: Awesome guys, great help you have been.   If i'm understanding the regex you're using, you're saying: "any character not 0-9 repeated at least once (but as many times as it appears); followed by a 0-9 repeated at least once; followed by any non 0-9 repeated at least once.  Is that correct?  How come the middle part has ( )'s around it while the other 2 parts of the regex do not?

Sorry to keep bothering you, i'm really trying to learn and understand regex as good as i can.

Comment: As a follow up, i found another great use of this application but the file names are slightly different structure:
SITE1_20130615000320_00027554229_IBX_Admission_Orders_page1.JPG.

It has a string of numbers (datetime stamp) _ followed by the encounter and then some alpha description.  What's a good way to capture the Encounter string without getting the datetime string?

Comment: Oh, i found out about the ( )'s from that link you posted.  That determines which part goes into the array.  If there are multiple groups of ( )'s it would be mutliple arrays (ary[1] and ary[2] for example).

Comment: And i think i answered my other question too... for a file with another string like the datetime stamp i could use this regex:  [^0-9]+([0-9]{8,11})[^0-9]+   as long as my first number string doesn't fall into the 8-11 digits i'm repeating.

Answer (score 3):

#### GNU sed

```
sed -r -e 's#(.*)#FILE:\t/tmp/imagetest/\1#;s/([0-9]*)(i[^i]*)$/\1\2\tENCOUNTER:\1/;1i -----TEST TAG FILE      ENCOUNTERS-----' -e '$aEND REPORT' file
```

```
-----TEST TAG FILE      ENCOUNTERS-----
FILE:   /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY0001275678image1.jpg      ENCOUNTER:0001275678
FILE:   /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY11134900211image2.jpg     ENCOUNTER:11134900211
FILE:   /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY19257012image3.jpg        ENCOUNTER:19257012
FILE:   /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY273142590image4.jpg       ENCOUNTER:273142590
END REPORT
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the commonly-written awk function "extract()" to extract a string that matches an RE:

```
awk -v re='<whatever>' '
function extract(str,regexp)
{ RMATCH = (match(str,regexp) ? substr(str,RSTART,RLENGTH) : "")
  return RSTART
}
extract($0,re) { print RMATCH }
'
```

Just set "re" to whatever you want to match, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
SURGERY0001275678image1.jpg
SURGERY11134900211image2.jpg
SURGERY19257012image3.jpg
SURGERY273142590image4.jpg

$ awk -v re='[[:digit:]]{8,11}' '
function extract(str,regexp)
{ RMATCH = (match(str,regexp) ? substr(str,RSTART,RLENGTH) : "")
  return RSTART
}
extract($0,re) { print RMATCH }
' file
0001275678
11134900211
19257012
273142590
```

or if you prefer a more specific solution using the same match()+substr() approach:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{ print "-----TEST TAG FILE\tENCOUNTERS-----" }
{ printf "FILE:  %s\tENCOUNTER: %d\n", $0, (match($0,/[[:digit:]]{8,11}/) ? substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) : 0) }
END{ print "END REPORT" }
' file
-----TEST TAG FILE      ENCOUNTERS-----
FILE:  SURGERY0001275678image1.jpg      ENCOUNTER: 1275678
FILE:  SURGERY11134900211image2.jpg     ENCOUNTER: 11134900211
FILE:  SURGERY19257012image3.jpg        ENCOUNTER: 19257012
FILE:  SURGERY273142590image4.jpg       ENCOUNTER: 273142590
END REPORT
```

Note that if all of your file names follow the same pattern and don't have other digits before the stream of 8-11 digits you care about, you could just use `[[:digit:]]+` as the matching RE instead of explicitly specifying the range `[[:digit:]]{8,11}` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ cat input
SURGERY0001275678image1.jpg
SURGERY11134900211image2.jpg
SURGERY19257012image3.jpg
SURGERY273142590image4.jpg

$ awk '{split($1,a,/[[:alpha:]]*/);print a[2]}' input
0001275678
11134900211
19257012
273142590
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "-----TEST TAG FILE\tENCOUNTERS-----";}
{print "FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/"$1,"\t","ENCOUNTER: ",gensub(/[^0-9]*([0-9]*).*/, "\\1", 1, $1);}
END{print "END REPORT";
}' image.list > upload.tag
```

Comment: You're missing the "how" parameter to gensub(): http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Comment: Thanks! It was just a coincidence that it was working before because the value the OP was interested was also the first digits in `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{encounter=$1; sub("^[^0-9]*([0-9]{8,11}).*", "\\1", encounter);
      print "FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/"$1,"\t","ENCOUNTER: ",encounter;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "-----TEST TAG FILE\tENCOUNTERS-----";}
{printf "FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/"$1"\tENCOUNTER: ";if($1~/[0-9]{8,11}/){sub(/
[0-9]+\.jpg$/,"",$1); gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/,"",$1);print $1}}
END{print "END REPORT";
}' image.list
```

will print

```
-----TEST TAG FILE      ENCOUNTERS-----
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY0001275678image1.jpg        ENCOUNTER: 0001275678
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY11134900211image2.jpg       ENCOUNTER: 11134900211
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY19257012image3.jpg          ENCOUNTER: 19257012
FILE:  /tmp/imagetest/SURGERY273142590image4.jpg         ENCOUNTER: 273142590
END REPORT
```